# Replace text with latex

Tags: writing, math

I wondered if it is possible to make emacs replace occurences of a/b with  $ {a \over b} $ , where a and b are integers or letters in the text.

Comment: Note that `{a \over b}` is TeX but depreciated in LaTeX. You should use `\frac{a}{b}` in LaTeX.

Comment: `M-x replace-regexp` should do the trick, if you are familiar with regex.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will look into regex

Comment: You can use calc-embedded to replace any formula in algebric syntax to latex syntax. The built-in command is C-x * E. It can be smart to bind a F key since you have to strike it twice to return to latex-mode

Answer (score 2):

Go to the beginning of your text and press <kbd>C-M-%</kbd>. That key sequence is bound to the command `query-replace-regexp`.

Give `\([+-]?[0-9]+\|\_<[[:alpha:]]\)/\([+-]?[0-9]+\|[[:alpha:]]\_>\)` as search string and `{\1 \\over \2}` as replacement and press <kbd>RET</kbd>.

Note that this searches for integers maybe composed of several digits and with optional sign + or -. Variables must consist of exactly one letter. Variables composed of several letters are ignored because of the symbol delimiters `\_<` and `\_>`.

No space is permitted between the variables/numbers and the slash.

Some comments on the used constructs in the regular expression:

- `\(...\)` delimit groups which you can refere to in the replacement string with `\1`, ..., `\9`
- `\\` in the replacement text is a literal backslash. (backslash alone is used for referencing groups in the search string)
- `[0-9]` is the character class consisteing of the characters from `0` to `9`
- `\|` is the or-operator. Match either the left-hand side or the right-hand side. Left-hand and right-hand side can be delimited by a group.
- `[[:alpha:]]` is the character class that matches one character within `A`-`Z` and `a`-`z`, they match actually more: characters with word-syntax.
- `\_<` and `\_>` are symbol boundaries at the beginning and the end, respectively.

Reason for this answer: 
The tag search for `[replace]` does not give a simple answer for that question. Most questions address more complicated cases.

Comment: Using [[:alnum:]]+ should simply that expression.

Comment: @AndreasRöhler No it doesn't. The OP says there may be letters or integers. Letters consist only of a single character while integers are composed of the optional sign and a sequence of digits. Thus those cases must be separated anyway.

Comment: Thanks, that worked